# floating popup.html div

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I noticed that the [Buffer app](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/noojglkidnpfjbincgijbaiedldjfbhh) for chrome does things a little differently with a floating div when the extension icon is clicked. How is this achieved?

I don't believe they do this in a new window since I am not seeing an addition window being spawned.

Basically what I need is a thickbox to be displayed when the icon is clicked.

Any insight on how this is done would be appreciated.

Comment: They are injecting HTML/CSS/JavaScript into the tab.

Comment: So I could inject a div into the open tab and use SimpleModal to display a lightbox?

Answer (score 0):

They're using an api from that background page, to listen to the click event for when the browser action button gets clicked.

Here's a link to that API page:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {'file': 'createPopup.js'}, function callBackStub(){})
});
```

***createPopup.js***

You're html will be in a string. I personally recommend writing this like this:

```
var widgetHtml = 
  '<div id="main">              '+
  '  <p>some stuff goes here</p>'+
  '</div>';
```

Then as your html grows, you can do a column edit of the beginning quote and end `'+`

Ok, now what you'll want to do is put your html in an iframe, but without setting a src property. Like this:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe); //fastest way to append to DOM: http://jsperf.com/insertbefore-vs-appendchild/2
iframe.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = widgetHtml;
```

WHY? So your stuff doesn't take on styles from the rest of the page.

Um, and then you can do a translateX or transition left/right position to slide the element into the page.